# List out the installed apps android

Tags: java, android

How to get the installed apps which are downloaded, not the applications (like contacts,  settings, camera,etc..).
 I am using the PackageManager, which returning entire applications (default + downloaded).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class AppList extends Activity {
 private ListView lView;
 private ArrayList results = new ArrayList();

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.main);
  lView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list1);
  PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();

  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
  intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

  List list = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
  for (ResolveInfo rInfo : list) {
   results.add(rInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo
     .loadLabel(pm).toString());
   Log.w("Installed Applications", rInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo
     .loadLabel(pm).toString());
  } 
  lView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, results));
    }
}
```